# Unable to connect to server using Paramiko package

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I'm trying to connect to my server using SSH with port 2022 (not 22) in Python. So I wrote the following code that uses Paramiko package:

```py
import sys
import paramiko

try:
  client = paramiko.SSHClient()
  client.load_system_host_keys()
  client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.WarningPolicy)
  client.connect('ccap@10.40.2.222', '2022', '', 'ccap')
finally:
  client.close()
```

But when I'm running it in my IDE (PyCharm) I get the following error:

> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/ecdsakey.py:164: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Support for unsafe construction of public numbers from encoded data will be removed in a future version. Please use EllipticCurvePublicKey.from_encoded_point
>     self.ecdsa_curve.curve_class(), pointinfo
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/mshapirs/PycharmProjects/OnlineTest.py/OnlineTest.py", line 9, in 
>       client.connect('ccap@10.40.2.222', '2022', '', 'ccap')
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 334, in connect
>       to_try = list(self._families_and_addresses(hostname, port))
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 204, in _families_and_addresses
>       hostname, port, socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 733, in getaddrinfo
>        for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
>
> socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide username as a separate parameter, not prepended to the host address.

[Look at the docs for `.connect`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.connect). It has `username` and `hostname`listed separately.